# URL Friendly regular expression

Tags: regex

Can anyone help me with regular expression for this:
basically I have a search form and users type in whatever keywords they want to search and when a search button is clicked, the search keyword is appended to the url (see examples below). Note the keyword may contain any character.

Example 1
Search key: whatever you want
URL: www.example.com/search/whatever+you+want/

Example 2
Search key: oh boy! what's going on?
URL: www.example.com/search/oh+boy!+what's+goin+on%3F

What regular expression can I use to capture all characters in the ASCII table between 32 to 126?

Comment: What do you really want to achieve? And why does it have to be a regexp?

Answer (score 2):

When I googled your question:

> What regular expression can I use to capture all characters in the ASCII table between 32 to 126?

the second hit was a site on [Regular Expressions](http://whitefiles.org/b1_s/1_free_guides/fg2cd/pgs/f02_regexp.htm) with precisely the answer you want:

```
/[[:print:]]*/
```

assuming POSIX character classes are supported

If they aren't, you can use:

```
/[\x20-\x81]*/
```

Answer (score 0):

In perl, at least, you could use something like:

```
/[\040-\176]/ # 32-126 in octal
```

However, whatever language you're using probably has a module / library for parsing URLs, and for reversing URL encoding in a more complete and correct way. It's probably better to use that than to use a regex. For example, perl has [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI).